# $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$, prove $\frac{a^3}{bc} +\frac{b^3}{ca} + \frac{c^3}{ab} \geq \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2c} + \frac{b^2 + c^2}{2a} + \frac{c^2 + a^2}{2b}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> $a$,$b$,$c \in \mathbb R^+$, prove that $$\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ca} + \frac{c^3}{ab} \geq \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2c} + \frac{b^2 + c^2}{2a} + \frac{c^2 + a^2}{2b}$$

**`My Attempt :`**

$\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ca} + \frac{c^3}{ab} \geq \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2c} + \frac{b^2 + c^2}{2a} + \frac{c^2 + a^2}{2b}$

or, $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge \frac{ab(a^2+b^2)+bc(b^2+c^2)+ca(c^2+a^2)}{2}$

or, $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)}{2} \ge \frac{ab(a^2+b^2)+bc(b^2+c^2)+ca(c^2+a^2)}{2}$

or, $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)}{2}$

*How to proceed further?*

And also tell if there's an more elegant way to it using rearrangement or Chebyshev!

Comment: A reminder to OP that all of your previous questions on inequalities should also be tagged as contest-math.

Comment: @IraeVid: Yes, *if* the question is from (or directly related to) a contest. In that case the source of the problem should also be provided.

Comment: @IraeVid yeah right but all of them are from pathfinder book and yeah the source might be the contests 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> Check if $${a^3\over b} + {b^3\over a}\geq a^2+b^2$$ is true,

> i.e. $$a^4+b^4\geq ab(a^2+b^2)$$

> i.e. $$(a-b)(a^3-b^3)\geq 0 $$

Answer (score 7):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $0 < a \le b \le c$. Then
$$
 a^4+ b^4 + c^4 \ge a^3 b + b^3 c + c^3 a \\
 a^4+ b^4 + c^4 \ge a b^3 + b c^3 + c a^3 \\
$$
using the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) twice. Adding these two inequalities and dividing by $2abc$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Any shorter way using rearrangement or chebyshev ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc: I did use the rearrangement inequality ...

Comment: I meant can't we directly apply rearrangement or chebyshev without doing those manipulations before 

Comment: @Ash_Blanc: You could also say “without loss of generality we can assume that $abc=1$” and then avoid the division by $abc$ but that would not really change the argument. – There are surely other proofs, but this is what I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging the inequality, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\sum_{\rm{cyc}} \left(\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ca}\right)&≥\sum_{\rm{cyc}}\left( \frac {a^2+b^2}{c}\right)\end{align}
$$

Then, multiplying both side of the inequality by $abc≠0$,  we have :

$$
\begin{align}a^4+b^4&≥\frac {\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}{2}\\
&≥ab\left(a^2+b^2\right) \tag {*}\end{align}
$$

Done .

---

$(^{*})\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\rm{Comment:}$

The following inequality

$$a^4+b^4≥\frac {\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}{2}$$

or equivalently,

$$(a^4+b^4)(1+1)≥\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2$$

can be simply derived from the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) .